# Control number of connections at server side

Tags: sockets, http, browser

I am writing embedded web server, which has only 4 hardware sockets. Sometimes Chrome which I use for testing gets into "connection refused" state for requested resources because it tries connecting more than 4 sockets concurrently. Is there any way to tell to the client (e.g. through HTTP response header) how many sockets server can handle, and/or how many free sockets device currently has?

**Edit**: I have just learned that I use *Connection: close* HTTP header for simplicity purposes, however can use *Connection: keep-alive* to allow several HTTP request through single connection. Not sure how it may impact the issue I described above, but what scares me that such "keep-alive" persistent connection is going to time-out within a minute => socket is totally locked for this time, while with "close" it frees immediately after data exchange.

Comment: What is a 'hardware socket'?

Comment: Hardware socket is API entity provided by the hardware allowing data exchange. Number of sockets actually is defined by the size of RAM buffers, in my case - 2 kBytes per socket (16 kBytes for RX and TX for all 4 sockets). I can not reconfigure the chip to have more than 4 sockets, because it is hardware limitation.

Answer (score 1):

'Connection refused' tells him that. You can't send the client anything after a failure, because there is no connection to send it over. You could build in a special HTTP request to tell him how many free sockets there currently are, but that request would use up a free socket. I wouldn't do it.

Comment: You described worst case scenario. However, imagine web server is idle, and client (e.g. Chrome) starts loading web page contents. On the first request server may be able to respond to client "I have only 4 sockets and currently only 3 is free" and then Chrome will keep it in mind not creating more than 3 or 4 concurrent connections.